# Pivot Dataframe in Python - stock market analysis

Tags: python, pivot-table, stock

I have the python dictionary

```
stockDict = {
    'Owned' : ['CTSH', 'GOOGL'],
    'Wishlist' : ['LAZY', 'CTSH', 'AAPL']
}
```

: Updated dictionary to have values with different array sizes.
@Youness Sadaan's solution worked perfectly!

I would like to transform it into a dataframe as given below:

```
    stockCode   Remarks
0   CTSH        Owned
1   GOOGL       Owned
2   LAZY        Wishlist
3   CTSH        Wishlist
3   AAPL        Wishlist
```

I started with converting the dictionary into a dataframe and use pivot_table to achieve what I need.

```
stockDf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["stockCode", "Remarks"])
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, *v) for k, v in stockDict.items()])
df.columns = ['Remarks'] + [f'stock{x}' for x in df.columns[1:]]
display(df)
```

I am stuck at this point as to how to achieve my desired output.

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values=['stock1', 'stock2', 'stock3', 'stock4'], index=None, columns='Remarks', aggfunc='first')
```

gives me the following:

```
Remarks Owned   Wishlist
stock1  CTSH    LAZY
stock2  GOOGL   AIRG
stock3  None    CLSK
stock4  None    CTSH
```

Could someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the melt step. Try the following code, and then simply rename your columns!

```
stockDict = {'Owned' : ['CTSH', 'GOOGL'],'Wishlist' : ['LAZY', 'AIRG', 'CLSK', 'CTSH']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(stockDict, orient = 'index')
df.T.melt()
```

Comment: Thank  you for your feedback, @Jadon . That worked perfectly for the situation listed above. I apologize, I oversimplified my data scenario - The dictionary may not always contain same number of array elements for given key. Example: stockDict = {'Owned' : ['CTSH', 'GOOGL'],'Wishlist' : ['LAZY', 'AIRG', 'CLSK', 'CTSH']}. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why you would want all of the empty cells for owned, but glad @YounessSaadna was able to help.

Comment: I actually do not need the empty cells for owned. But I thought I would be able to exclude those from the Dataframe later. Excuse me if that sound a dirty way to get rid of those - I am still a beginner.

Comment: You're right, you'll exclude them later. Sorry, there's nothing wrong with having them be empty, I just think you should try and avoid creating a solution where you have to add that parameter if you try to append to the DataFrame. Check out my edit. There's a super simple way to do what you want without iterating.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `melt()` function will be better and easy.

I edited your code to give the same output you want:

```
stockDict = {'Owned' : ['CTSH', 'GOOGL'],'Wishlist' : ['LAZY', 'AIRG', 'CLSK', 'CTSH']}


stockDf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["stockCode", "Remarks"])
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, *v) for k, v in stockDict.items()])
df.columns = ['Remarks'] + [f'stock{x}' for x in df.columns[1:]]


df3=df.melt(id_vars=['Remarks'], value_vars=['stock1', 'stock2','stock3','stock4'],value_name='stockCode')[['Remarks','stockCode']]

df3=df3.sort_values(by=['Remarks'])

display(df3)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    Remarks stockCode
0     Owned      CTSH
2     Owned     GOOGL
4     Owned      None
6     Owned      None
1  Wishlist      LAZY
3  Wishlist      AIRG
5  Wishlist      CLSK
7  Wishlist      CTSH
```

Comment: @baliepages why did you change the accepted answer?